# Flutter Reading static variable during its initialization

Tags: flutter, static

I have a bool value to be pass from a checkbox in another screen which is *valueToSend* from *SubmitForm()* class. how can i get access to that variable so that the error go away and the *value* can be use as parameter in *parts*. The error is **reading static variable during its initialization**.

```
var value = SubmitForm().valueToSend; //here is the error come 

final header = ['Parts', 'Check'];

final parts = [
  Part(parts: 'Conveyor Belt', check: value ? 'done' : 'have issue'),];
     
    
class SubmitForm extends StatelessWidget {      

final bool valueToSend;

final data = parts.map((Part) => [Part.parts, Part.check]).toList();
}
```

Comment: do you need to access your function of A class from B?

Comment: The instance member 'valueToSend' can't be accessed in an initializer. what it mean?

Comment: I didnot get what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to get it.

```
class SubmitForm extends StatelessWidget {


final String text;
final String taskName;
final currentDate;
final dropdownValue;
final bool valueToSend;

final pdf = pw.Document();

  writeOnPdf() {
    final parts = [
      Part(parts: 'Conveyor Belt', check: valueToSend ? 'done' : 'have issue'), //i got it now
//      Part(parts: 'Gear Motor', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'Pulley&Roller', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'Side Frame', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'Motor', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'DMS', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'Sensor', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'Beacon', check: 'done'),
//      Part(parts: 'E/stop', check: 'done'),
    ];
    final data = parts.map((Part) => [Part.parts, Part.check]).toList();

    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a5,
        margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(32),
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Header(level: 0, child: pw.Text('Date:$currentDate')),
            pw.Header(
                // show image from the asset image TODO provide image to pdf
                level: 1,
                child: pw.Text('Baggage Handling System T2, MA(SEPANG) SDN BHD',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold))),
            pw.Header(level: 2, child: pw.Text('PPM Inspection Check Sheet')),
            pw.Paragraph(
                text: '$taskName Subsystem $text done by shift $dropdownValue'),
            pw.Table.fromTextArray(
              headers: header,
              data: data,
              headerDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                color: PdfColors.grey300,
              ),
            ),
          ];
        }));
  }
```